# Deploying my nlkt chatbot to web using django

Tags: html, django, backend, chatbot

I just developed a chatbot for a client using nltk frame work, the bot works well but am having it difficult deploying it on django,tried using html form get method as my user input but it not working nor my bot response is not displaying...can someone please put me through the steps to follow.....thanks in advance

I did run my code on the views on my django project if I call the url for the front page, my bot runs in my system but nothing works at the front end

Comment: Show what you have tried and what is not working. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand how to ask a good question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.